# AWS Step function invokes a lambda dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to invoke a lambda dynamically with AWS Step functions. This is my state machine definition:

```
{
    "Comment": "Manage a lambda invoke. Inputs: timeout_seconds, function, qualifier, payload.",
    "StartAt": "Lambda function",
    "States": {
        "Lambda function": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "TimeoutSecondsPath": "$.timeout_seconds",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "FunctionName": "$.function",
                "Qualifier": "$.qualifier",
                "Payload": "$.payload"
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my state machine input:

```
{"timeout_seconds": 10, "function": "lambda_a", "qualifier": "", "payload": "{}"}
```

But, when I called it, it returns this error:

```
'status': 'FAILED', 'error': 'Lambda.AWSLambdaException', 'cause': "2 validation errors detected: Value '$.function' at 'functionName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\\d{1}:)?(\\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]+)(:(\\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?; Value '$.qualifier' at 'qualifier' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (|[a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+)
```

I get the same error also with this input:

```
{"timeout_seconds": 10, "function": "arn:aws:lambda:{MY_AWS_REGION}:{MY_ID}:function:lambda_a", "qualifier": "$LATEST", "payload": "{}"}
```

Comment: When you want to interpolate on the right side the left side needs to end with `.$`: `"TimeoutSecondsPath.$": "$.timeout_seconds"` / `"FunctionName.$": "$.function"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like that you don't have `$.qualifier` set to a valid value in your example [needs to match `(\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestParameters)

Basically either `$LATEST` ***or*** a string with one or more characters in `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `$`, `_`, `-`

Try setting a default value in your input

```json
{
  "...": "...",
  "qualifier": "$LATEST" // or some other valid alias in your aws env
}
```